# How to create a new column in pandas dataframe based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with the following columns:

```
d = {'find_no': [1, 2, 3], 'zip_code': [32351, 19207, 8723]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

When there are 5 digits in the zip_code column, I want to return True. When there are not 5 digits, I want to return the "find_no".
Sample output would have the results in an added column to the dataframe, corresponding to the row it's referencing.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try np.where:

```py
import numpy as np

df['result'] = np.where(df['zip_code'].astype(str).str.len() == 5, True, df['find_no'])
```

Only downside with this approach is that NumPy will convert your True values to 1's, which could be confusing. An approach to keep the values you want is to do

```py
import numpy as np

df['result'] = np.where(df['zip_code'].astype(str).str.len() == 5, 'True', df['find_no'].astype(str))
```

The downside here being that you lose the meaning of those values by casting them to strings. I guess it all depends on what you're hoping to accomplish.